# Is it possible to trigger JIT compilation for an entire .NET web application at runtime?

Tags: asp.net, .net, compilation, .net-4.5

I'm aware it's possible to use Ngen to precompile an application. Is it possible to easily force a runtime JIT compilation of parts or the entire application programmatically speaking?

The use case is warming (aka forcing JIT compilation) of a multitenant application on application start without hitting a url.

Comment: how is your app hosted? in iis?

Comment: if it is iis: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/oct/02/use-iis-application-initialization-for-keeping-aspnet-apps-alive

Comment: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers class is a place to start.  The PrepareMethod will JIT a specific method, but preparing all of them is a bit larger scope.

Comment: It's hosted as an app service in Azure. (non-containerized)